# How to resize and print lesser values than what I have?

Tags: c++

I want to reduce the vector of my program. Basically print out lesser values. For example, I manage to search for what I need but I cannot reduce it. I searched for first choice as CC and got it. I also manage to sort it by GPA. It gave me 5 outputs which is correct but I only need 3 with the highest GPA. I don't know whether that is possible with my method.

This is a snippet of my my txt file:

The sequence is First,Second,Third,GPA,Name

```
CC,DR,TP,3.8,AlexKong
SN,SM,TP,4.0,JasonTan
DR,TP,SC,3.6,AstaGoodwin
SC,TP,DR,2.8,MalcumYeo
SN,SM,TP,3.7,DavidLim
SN,SM,TP,3.2,SebastianHo
SC,TP,DR,4.0,PranjitSingh

and so on...
```

Below is my code:

```
while (File >> line) //parse all the lines
{
    v.push_back(line);
}

cout << "\nCC Students: " << endl;
for (auto str : v){
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater());
    if (!str.find("CC")){
        cout << str.substr(13, 100) << " " << str.substr(9, 3) << "\n"; //will print all fields where CC is found
    }
}
```

And got this output which is correct:

```
MuruArun 3.9
AlexKong 3.8
DamianKoh 3.7
MattWiliiams 3.3
IrfanMuhaimin 3.3
```

After that I realise that I cannot easily resize it. Then I updated it. I tried to search if the first element is CC then try to put all those in a new vector where I can resize it and display lesser values.

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater());
    for (auto str : v){
        if (!str.find("CC")){     //tried to search for all the lines with CC as first choice
            vector <string> CC;   //tried to create a new vector to put the lines
            string line;
            while (File >> line) //parse all the lines
            {
                CC.push_back(line);  //tried to put the lines into one vector.
                CC.resize(3);        //tried to resize so that I can only print top 3.
            }
            cout << str.substr(13, 100) << " " << str.substr(9, 3) << "\n"; //will print all fields where CC is found
        }
```

So that I can output only top 3 highest instead of all 5 like this:

```
MuruArun 3.9
AlexKong 3.8
DamianKoh 3.7
```

But obviously I am doing something wrong somewhere. I don't know whether my logic is wrong or am I doing it wrongly. I hope someone can point out what I am doing wrong and guide me along. I am not good at this so apologies for all this weird attempts but I hope I can show you what I mean by doing these.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move the `CC` vector outside of the loop.
2. Push matching lines into `CC.
3. Break the loop once `CC` is size 3.

i.e.

```
while (File >> line) //parse all the lines
{
    v.push_back(line);
}
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater());

cout << "\nCC Students: " << endl;
std::vector<std::string> CC;
for (auto str : v)
{
    if (str.find("CC") == 0)
    {
        CC.push_back(str);
        if (CC.size() == 3)
            break;
    }
}

// now do whatever you want with CC. It has at-most three 
// lines in it, and all of them start with CC.
```

That's it. Honestly I question whether you even need the second vector. In reality this would do what you want:

```
while (File >> line) //parse all the lines
{
    v.push_back(line);
}
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater());

cout << "\nCC Students: " << endl;
int cc = 0;
for (auto str : v)
{
    if (str.find("CC") == 0)
    {
        // TODO: print whatever you want from the current line.

        // ...then
        if (++cc == 3)
            break;
    }
}
```

In the first case, you retain the string in a separate container. In the second case you do your printing in the primary loop and be done with it. Either will probably work in your case. the choice is yours which to actually do.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. The code works. Very very much appreciated. I never knew that I can use break; I never used that before. Anyways, thanks again. Take care!